# NPM Lite Server misses files of Angular 2 app

Tags: angular, npm

When I run my Angular 2 app locally running `npm start` I encounter that some of my typescript files are not delivered correctly by the NPM lite server.

In my template I have a toolbar:

```
<p-toolbar>
     <div class="ui-toolbar-group-left">
        <button pButton type="button" label="Delete" icon="fa-trash" (click)="menuButtonDeleteClicked()"></button>
      </div>
</p-toolbar>
```

I have one Typescript class representing one web search, having amongst others an identifier member:

```
export class WebSearchDto {
    private id: number;
}
```

In the component that belongs to the template above I want to implement the delete functionality as follows:

```
 private menuButtonDeleteClicked(): void {
    var webSearchId: number = this.selectedWebSearch.getId();
}
```

As expected, the function `getId()` is missing, so I add it to the web search class.

```
export class WebSearchDto {
    private id: number;
    public getId(): number {
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

After saving the file gets compiled, however the browser does not refresh (thought browser sync would take care) and when I click the delete button, I receive the JS error message

> this.selectedWebSearch.getId is not a function

When I look at the app sources in the Chrome web console, I see that the JS file that contains the web search class is missing. The respective file exists on the file system and I can access it in the browser using localhost:3000 as hostname.

**Is there any idea why the latest changes are not reflected?**

Comment: Could you please add some codes that allows us to know what is the main issue, because we cannot give you any solutions without the correct use case and other codes that you have used and causing issues.

Comment: What are the files seems to be missing add the relevant code along with error in console if any.

Comment: I added more information